# Eigenvalues of anti-circulant matrices

Tags: eigenvector, matrices

Is there any theorem to find the eigenvalues of any anti-circulant matrix using the equivalent (with the same first row) circulant matrix. I found out that,
for any anti-circulant matrix, the eigenvalues (taken as $\mu$) of the anti-circulant matrix can be written as,
\begin{equation}
\mu = \pm \mid{\lambda_j}\mid
\label{mu_alpha}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of 1-circulant matrix with the same first row. This seems valid since any anti-circulant matrix should be symmetric resulting in real eigenvalues.

Can anyone send me a link to any reference which has this proof..? or can you please comment if you think that this should not be correct ?

Comment: Hint: the square of your anti-circulant matrix has the same eigenvectors as the corresponding circulant matrix.

Comment: Simul-posted, in a major breach of etiquette, to math.stackexchange, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62466/eigenvalues-of-anti-circulant-matrices-using-1-circulant-matrices

Comment: @Gerry: please don't bite the newbies.  While it is better not to simul-post, neither the mathoverflow faq nor the math.stackexchange faq says that explicitly.  In any case, a friendly hint would suffice.

Comment: Extremely sorry for simul-post in math.stackexchange, as I didn't know that these two are similar. Can anyone help me to understand what math.stackexchange and math.overflow.. and the differences of them, so that I could post my questions correctly according to the rules.. 